# How to derive the probability distribution of subsystems in microcanonical ensemble?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

For example, we have one microcanonical system with two subsystems A and B which can exchange energy. the probability of finding subsystem A in Energy Ea is :

$$ P(Ea) = \frac{\Omega_{A}(Ea)*\Omega_{B}(E-Ea)}{\Omega_{A+B}(E)} $$

I am stuck here because I cannot expand it around E since Ea (like the derivation in the canonical ensemble) is not necessarily much smaller than E. What should I do next?

Comment: Is there are a particular expression you're trying to derive?

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the standard result for the probability of subsystem $A$ being at energy $E_a$ we have to assume that subsystem $B$ is a "bath", i.e., much larger than the subsystem of interest. This condition fixes the temperature of $A$ to a constant value even as its energy fluctuates.

Mathematically it is possible to speak of the energy distribution regardless of the relative size of the subsystems. In this case, however, the energy distribution in $A$ is correlated to the energy distribution in $B$. By making $B$ infinite its energy distribution becomes a Dirac delta and the energy distribution in $A$ becomes a Gaussian distribution with a non vanishing variance except asymptotically as the size of the system increases.